# how openstack remove offline host node by kolla-ansible

Tags: deployment, ansible, openstack, offline

I have an offline **host node** which includes (**compute node, control node and storage node**). This **host node** was shutdown by accident and can't recover to online.  All services about that node are **`down`** and **`enable`** but I can't set to **`disable`**.

So I can't [remove the host](https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/adding-and-removing-hosts.html) by:

```
kolla-ansible -i multinode stop --yes-i-really-really-mean-it --limit node-17
```

I get this error:

```
TASK [Gather facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node-17]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host node-17 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
node-17         : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

How can I remove that offline host node? THX.

> > PS: Why I remove that offline host?

```
node-14(online)  : **manage node which kolla-ansible installed**; compute node, control node and storage node
node-15(online)  : compute node, control node and storage node
node-17(offline) : compute node, control node and storage node
osc99  (adding)  : compute node, control node and storage node
```

Because when I deploy a **new host**(osc99) with (the **multinode** file had comment the `node-17` line):

```
kolla-ansible -i multinode deploy --limit osc99
```

`kolla-ansible` will report error:

```
TASK [keystone : include_tasks] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
included: .../share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/keystone/tasks/init_fernet.yml for osc99

TASK [keystone : Waiting for Keystone SSH port to be UP] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [osc99]

TASK [keystone : Initialise fernet key authentication] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [osc99 -> node-14]

TASK [keystone : Run key distribution] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [osc99 -> node-14]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["docker", "exec", "-t", "keystone_fernet", "/usr/bin/fernet-push.sh"], "delta": "0:00:04.006900", "end": "2021-07-12 10:14:05.217609", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 255, "start": "2021-07-12 10:14:01.210709", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Warning: Permanently added '[node.15]:8023' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\nssh: connect to host node.17 port 8023: No route to host\r\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\r\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]", "stdout_lines": ["Warning: Permanently added '[node.15]:8023' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.", "", "ssh: connect to host node.17 port 8023: No route to host", "", "rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]", "rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]"]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
osc99                      : ok=120  changed=55   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=31   rescued=0    ignored=1
```

How could I fixed this error, this is the main point whether or not I can remove the offline host.

Maybe I could fixed that by change the **init_fernet.yml** file:

```
node-14:~$ cat .../share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/keystone/tasks/init_fernet.yml
---
- name: Waiting for Keystone SSH port to be UP
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ api_interface_address }}"
    port: "{{ keystone_ssh_port }}"
    connect_timeout: 1
  register: check_keystone_ssh_port
  until: check_keystone_ssh_port is success
  retries: 10
  delay: 5

- name: Initialise fernet key authentication
  become: true
  command: "docker exec -t keystone_fernet kolla_keystone_bootstrap {{ keystone_username }} {{ keystone_groupname }}"
  register: fernet_create
  changed_when: fernet_create.stdout.find('localhost | SUCCESS => ') != -1 and (fernet_create.stdout.split('localhost | SUCCESS => ')[1]|from_json).changed
  until: fernet_create.stdout.split()[2] == 'SUCCESS' or fernet_create.stdout.find('Key repository is already initialized') != -1
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
  run_once: True
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['keystone'][0] }}"

- name: Run key distribution
  become: true
  command: docker exec -t keystone_fernet /usr/bin/fernet-push.sh
  run_once: True
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['keystone'][0] }}"
```

by changing the `delegate_to: "{{ groups['keystone'][0] }}`? But I can't implement that.

Comment: You say "can't set to disable". How do you disable the services, and what happens when you try? If it weren't for this remark, I would tell you to disable and remove Nova services, Neutron agent(s) and whatever else is running there and take the node out of the inventory.

Comment: Based on my experience with kolla-ansible, it basically survives a complete shutdown without problems. The only problem which can sometimes appears in my kolla single-node all-in-one setup was, that the docker-containers restart in an bad order after a restart of the host. To solve this in my case it helps to stop all kolla-containers and restart them manually in the correct order, starting with mariadb and rabbitmq and so on. Maybe it works for your problem too.